# How to use Autolayout to achieve result as per shown screen

Tags: ios, objective-c, user-interface, autolayout, xcode8

I'm developing an app where I'm facing an issue to achieve one UI layout only for iPhone devices. This is the layout that I'd like to achieve:

[image: This is an output I'd like to achieve for all iPhone Devices]

I want to achieve overlapped views that layout should be same on every device from 5s to 7 plus.

Comment: What exactly is confusing you? How to arrange views related to each other? How to put a view behind another view? Or how  to handle it on different screens?

Comment: @AleksandrMedvedev yes I want to achieve overlapped views that layout should be same on every device from 5s to 7 plus .Hope you understand

Comment: If you share the 4 images - background, heart and two faces - I think I can help.

Comment: @DonMag Thanks, Image sharing is confidential they don't give permit me .If you can help me try to use any images for background and heart shape from google.Any help will be really appreciated

Comment: Hello Folks May I know why downvote ? can they explain me what is wrong in this question? Please downvoter suggest me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The key is setting proportional constraints.

Start with adding a `UIView` to hold the 4 elements - background, man, woman and heart.

Add a `UIImage` for the background, and pin the edges to the edges of the view - that's the easy part.

Add a `UIImage` for the Man...

- Set the Aspect Ratio to 1:1 to keep it square (well, round in this case).
- Set the Height constraint equal to the Height of the "containing" view, but then set the multiplier to less than 1 to make it relative to the view. In this case, 0.6 is pretty close.
- Set constraints for Centered Horizontally and Vertically... then set the Multipliers to keep the image left and above the centers. 0.64 on horizontal, and 0.9 on vertical work pretty good.

Add a `UIImage` for the Woman...

- Set the Height and Width constraints equal to the Man image.
- Set constraints for Centered Horizontally and Vertically... then set the Multipliers to keep the image right and below the centers. 1.4 on horizontal, and 1.2 on vertical work pretty good.

Add a `UIImage` for the Heart...

- Set the Aspect Ratio to 1:1 (or whatever gives you the proper ratio for your heart image).
- Set the Height constraint equal to the Height of the "containing" view, but then set the multiplier to less than 1 to make it relative to the view. In this case, 0.15 is pretty close.
- Set constraints for Centered Horizontally and Vertically... then it will need a little adjustment o note Vertical 1.05 worked for me.

Now, you just need to set appropriate constraints for the "containing" view, and all the elements will scale and position themselves within it.

When you're all done, it should (hopefully) look like this:

[image]

I put the project up in a GitHub repo for you to look at: https://github.com/DonMag/AnotherLayoutExample

Comment: Thank you for your efforts will check it and let you know .thanks again :-)

Comment: Thanks for your help .I'm still not getting aspect ratio wise rounded corner while doing it programmatically (for Man, Woman image assume I'm fetching images from remote URL and then set corner radius and border ) any suggestions?

Comment: First guess --- you have your `UIImageView` contentMode set to Fill when you want Aspect Fit, or Aspect Fit when you want Aspect Fill, or vice-versa... Show a screen-cap of what you're getting?

Comment: Thank you for your reply . Can you suggest me where should I provide you screenshot ?